# Dúvida em relação a métodos de dimensionamento em um Frame

Tags: java, swing

Qual é a diferença entre o método `setSize()` e o método `setPrefferedSize()` em um Frame, e em qual situação deve se utilizar cada um?

Comment: É interessante sempre procurar a documentação antes, suas ultimas perguntas estão respondidas nela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método [`setPreferredSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setPreferredSize-java.awt.Dimension-) é herdado da classe `Component`, e como o próprio nome sugere, ele define um tamanho preferido para o `JFrame`. É recomendado sua utilização quando estamos fazendo uso dos [**Gerenciadores de Layout**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), pois esta é a forma que informamos a ele de que queremos que o componente seja, dentro do possível, daquele tamanho. Claro que ele pode ignorar este valor, dependendo de seu funcionamento e do espaço necessário para a distribuição de outros componentes na tela, e até devido a resolução do monitor também, mas normalmente os gerenciadores utilizam esse tamanho como base e o respeitam na hora de renderizar o componente.

Outros métodos que podem ser usados em conjunto com este para proporcionar maior controle do tamanho do componente são o [`setMaximumSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setMaximumSize-java.awt.Dimension-) e [`setMinimumSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setMinimumSize-java.awt.Dimension-), que definem, respectivamente, o tamanho máximo e minimo do componente.

Já o método [`setSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize-java.awt.Dimension-) define de forma da janela, de forma manual, diferente do método anterior que apenas sugere um tamanho ao gerenciador de layouts, mas também pode ser ignorado conforme o gerenciador utilizado. Você poderá utiliza-lo se o container do componente que for definir o tamanho não possuir um gerenciador de layouts ativo, caso contrário, poderá também ser ignorado.

Em via de regra, deve-se sempre utilizar o primeiro, haja visto que a não utilização de um gerenciador de layout pode trazer complicações muito maiores do que o gerenciamento de tamanho dos componentes.

Fontes:

- [Java: Difference between the setPreferredSize() and setSize() methods in components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783880/5524514)
- Documentação das classes [`Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) e [`Window`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html).