# Como remover adicionar/remover painel conforme selecao de checkbox?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Estou adicionando um painel na parte inferior de um `JFrame`, quando um `checkbox` esta selecionado, e quando desmarco ele, remover o painel, e deixar apenas o checkbox, porém, eu não estou conseguindo, acho que o gerenciador de layout esta impedindo o efeito que eu queria.

Minha dúvida é, como eu posso remover o painel, e deixar o cheque box sempre no canto inferior esquerdo, ocupando pouco espaço ?

Ex:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

O que eu fiz:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();

    public Test() {
        setTitle("Teste");
        getContentPane().add(desktopPane);
        add("South", new Info(comp()));
        setSize(700, 450);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private JComponent comp() {
        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        painel.add(new JLabel("Informações ... "));
        return painel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new Test();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Info extends JPanel {
    private JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Click");
    private JComponent component;

    public Info(JComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
        add(checkBox);

        checkBox.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                component.setVisible(true);
                component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
            } else {
                component.setVisible(false);
                component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
            }
            revalidate();
        });

        add(checkBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(component, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que ta usando desktoppane pra algo tao trivial? Qual a necessidade?

Comment: No meu sisteminha, eu uso, ele tem mais telas, menus e etc. Não quis perder tempo colocando isso aqui, já que não vai influenciar.

Comment: Precisa de um painel pra esse JLabel mesmo?

Comment: O label foi so para mostrar, vou colocar outras coisas, o importante, é exbir e remover esse painel, deixando o label sempre la no canto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz algumas alterações no seu código para que funcionasse corretamente:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

public class JCheckBoxComJpanelLado extends JFrame {

    private JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
    private Info infoPanel =  new Info();

    public JCheckBoxComJpanelLado() {

        setTitle("Teste");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 450));

        getContentPane().add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel auxPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        auxPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 30));
        auxPanel.setBackground(desktopPane.getBackground());

        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Click");

        checkBox.addItemListener(e -> infoPanel.setVisible(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED));

        auxPanel.add(checkBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        auxPanel.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        getContentPane().add(auxPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new JCheckBoxComJpanelLado());
    }
}

class Info extends JPanel {

    public Info() {

        add(new JLabel("Informações ... "));
        setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

O que mudei no código foi o seguinte:

- Esse catch pegando `Exception` é um desperdício de recurso, se não sabe se irá tratar uma exceção, não adicione try/catchs genericos, pois eles não ajudam em nada no código.
- quando se trabalha com layout, você precisa utilizar *tamanhos preferidos*, e como eu explico [**nesta outra resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282364/28595), o método `setSize()` não é o ideal para se usar nestas situações. O método `pack()` deve ser invocado para que a tela seja renderizada corretamente, levando em consideração estes tamanhos;
- Como o checkbox irá controlar a visibilidade do outro painel, eu o transformei em atributo de classe e movi como componente direto na tela, isso facilita o controle de visibilidade e simplifica o código;
- criei um painel auxiliar para comportar o checkbox e o outro painel no rodapé da janela. Tive que defini a altura(`Integer.MAX_VALUE` é para deixar a largura   a cargo do layoutManager) pois ao exibir o outro painel, o checkbox e ele pareciam ter tamanhos diferentes, e isso corrige esse problema.
- para dar o efeito do painel auxiliar parecer ficar mais curto quando o painel `Info`não estiver visível, defini a cor do background dele para a mesma do seu desktopPane. com cores iguais, eles se misturam na tela.
- No painel auxiliar eu utilizei [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) por não me forçar a definir tamanhos personalizados para o checkbox e o painel `info`, fazendo esse ultimo preencher o restante do espaço a direita sem ser preciso definir nada.
- creio que o painel precise começar oculto, para que seja exibido apenas quando o checkbox for selecionado. Por isso alterei a visibilidade logo após ele ter sido criado. O `revalidate()` é desnecessário neste caso.
- simplifiquei a alteração de estado do checkbox, afinal, a visibilidade do painel info é de acordo com o estado de seleção dele, logo não é preciso fazer um if somente para validar isso.

O resultado fica:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Recomendo a leitura do [tutorial a respeito de layouts managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para aprender melhor como eles funcionam e como manusear e combina-los sem problemas.

Comment: eu tinha tentando colocar o painel do checkbox menor, pois eu estava tentando deixar ele do lado do painel com o label informações. A intenção era deixar o área ocupada pelo comp() livre, pois ele fica na frente de uma tela se ele for muito grande. Dessa forma, msm que vc oculte ele, o painel do checkbox ainda vai ocupar aquela area

Comment: @AlunoOracle isso beira a gambiarra e nao é possivel de fazer de forma simples, e nem com esse codigo generico que voce forneceu. Pode ser que a ele funcione bem, mas se o seu for diferente, pode nao funcionar.

Comment: e mandar ele para traz do desktopPane, é possível ?

Comment: @AlunoOracle na verdade, agora relendo sua duvida, eu entendi o que está querendo fazer e após uma breve pesquisa, vi que é sim possivel organizar componentes por sobreposicao. Vou editar a resposta com essa opção.

Comment: @AlunoOracle veja a atualização.

Comment: é isso ! Obrigado !